# Clickable image in WebGrid inside a Controller (via Ajax )?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I'm using the MVC3 WebGrid inside my controller.I need to have an image in a column,such that when you click on that image, data is passed to an action inside any controller.I want to do this via Ajax, i.e. clicking on the image shouldn't cause a post back,it should be an Ajax call to an Action on some Controller.And I would like to pass an object (model), not any string,or int, or whatever).

```
public ActionResult AddInGrid(AjaxModel m)
        {
            if (Session["ajaxmodel"] == null)
            {
                Session.Add("ajaxmodel", a.am);
            }
            List<AjaxModel> list = (List<AjaxModel>)Session["ajaxmodel"];
            list.Insert(0, m);
            Session.Add("ajaxmodel", list);
            WebGrid g = new WebGrid(list);
            IHtmlString s = g.GetHtml();
            string s1 = s.ToString();
            return Json(new { text = s1 });
        }
```

What should be put inside of GetHtml() method??
EDIT: Here's what I've tried so far, and it isn't working:
I've found out what HTML renders on Ajax.ActionLink and tried to incorporate that

```
    WebGrid g = new WebGrid(list);
    string link = string.Format(@"<a data-ajax='true' data-ajax-method='GET' data-ajax-mode='replace' href='/Home/Delete/{0}' />Delete</a>",item.fname);   
 IHtmlString s = g.GetHtml(g.Columns(g.Column(format:link)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            columnName: "", 
            format: 
                @<text>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink(
                        "Delete", 
                        "delete", 
                        "home", 
                        new AjaxOptions { 
                            UpdateTargetId = "sometargetdiv", 
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                        }
                    )
                 </text>
        )
    )
)
```

As far as passing an entire model to the action is concerned, well, you could use the routeValues parameter and pass the different properties as query string parameters:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "delete", 
    "home", 
    new {
        fname = item.fname,
        lname = item.lname
        .... and so on for each property you want to fetch back
    },
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "sometargetdiv", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
    }
)
```

Comment: This works inside a View, I need it inside a Controller.It's not working there

Comment: What do you need inside a controller? Why are you generating HTML inside a controller in the first place? That's not what a controller is meant to do. A controller manipulates a model and renders a view. That's entirely the view's responsibility. You could use HTML helpers in those views to encapsulate some commonly repeating logic.

Comment: I was reading a bit, and it seems I have to create an instance of AjaxHelper class,also of ViewContext,etc..can't make much of that,I'm new to MVC

Comment: @karank, you can't do that in a controller. You don't have a ViewContext inside a controller.

Comment: Well,I have this situation in which I click on this button, and a record should get added to the Grid, also the content of the page should change.Then after making all the changes,I have a Next button which leads me to the next page.So I decided to Add a row via Ajax,and same for updation deletion.

Comment: Thing is there are 2 such sections(one of which has this WebGrid), and in both i need to save data,update the look of the page, and then move on to the next page.So I thought of doing the saving via Ajax and then doing a postback on the Next button click

Comment: So, will I just have to do a PostBack for adding/editing/deleting data on the grid,or is there any other way to do all this via Ajax?

Comment: @karank, you could do it via AJAX. You generate columns (in your view) for the grid that will contain Ajax.ActionLinks (as shown in my answer) that will trigger AJAX requests to the different actions that will take care of the actual processing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9127/discussion-between-karan-k-and-darin-dimitrov)